# PyQt Designer - promote widget but do not add 'import' line?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

Using Qt Designer for PyQt5, I promote a widget to be an instance of a custom widget.  This works well.

Is there a way to instruct Qt Designer or pyuic5 to NOT add the import line for custom widget classes?

[Qt Designer does not let you leave the Header File line blank.]

The custom widget class is already defined and coded up in the same .py file as the rest of the main window code and top level code - the same file that imports the file generated by pyuic5 - and can't easily be broken out to a separate file for various reasons, basically because it wasn't written in a clean modular fashion.  So, the import line added by pyuic5 is not needed and causes problems.

Snippets from the file generated by pyuic5:

```
...
   self.tableView = CustomTableView(self.parentWidget)
...
from customTableView import CustomTableView
...
```

The "right" way to do things would be to refactor such that the custom widget class could be defined in its own file, so that it could be imported by the file created by pyuic5. But, that is problematic since the custom class calls methods from other classes also defined in the top level file, and also calls top level functions and variables defined in the top level file.

A few brute-force solutions come to mind: just comment out the line by hand, and/or modify the runtime code to comment out that line by hand before importing the generated file.  Both of those are about as far from the "right" way to do things as you could get.

Comment: No, you cannot, it's automatically added by pyuic, and *must* be there because otherwise the script would crash due to a `NameError`. You must rethink the script and ensure that whatever that must *not* be executed when imported is added to the standard `if __name__ == '__main__':` block(s). Besides, from what you're describing, it seems that your script has serious reference issues, so instead of trying to fix uic (which you can't for the reason above), you should solve *those* issues.

Comment: Putting the one-time code inside `if __name == '__main__'` is a good route forward, thanks.  However, poking around, I did just find another option: in Designer, change the header file for the promoted widget class to be the name of the top level code file that imports the generated file.  This seems like it would be a circular import, but, it does seem to cause any issues or tracebacks, maybe because the generated file is only importing one class rather than the whole file, by doing 'from <topfile> import CustomTableView'.  This seems like a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to this question is 'no, you cannot' from musicamante in comment to the original question.

So, here's a workaround that accomplishes the original intent: in Designer, change the header file for the promoted widget class to be the name of the top level code file (ending in .h instead of .py since it was originally written for C++) that imports the generated file and defines the custom widget class:

[image]

Then, the file generated by pyuic includes this line:

```
from topFile import CustomTableView
```

Since topFile.py imports the file generated by pyuic, this might seem like a circular import, but apparently it is fine and not circular, since the line above is only trying to (re)import one class, rather than (re)importing the entire file topFile.py which would be circular.